# Generate ordered list of sum between elements in large lists

Tags: algorithm

I'm not sure whether this question should be posted in math of overflow, but here we go.

I have an arbitrary amount of ordered lists (say 3 for example) with numerical values. These lists can be long enough that trying all combinations of values becomes too computationally heavy.

What I need is to get an ordered list of possible sums when picking one value from each of the lists. Since the lists can be large, I only want the N smallest sums.

What I've considered is to step down one of the lists for each iteration. This however misses many cases that would have been possible if another list would have been chosen for that step.

An alternative would be a recursive solution, but that would generate many duplicate cases instead.

Is there any known methods that could solve such a problem?

Comment: what do you mean by duplicated cases? The possible sum list can not have duplicated values in it?

Comment: can you add some examples to help understand question

Comment: What I meant by that a recursive solution would generate duplicates is that it can reach the same index combination in several ways. I.e. (0,0,0)->(0,0,1)->(0,1,1) and (0,0,0)->(0,1,0)->(0,1,1). I tried to make some nice ascii examples, but SO formatting made the useless. Anyways, MBo's solution solved the problem brilliantly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let we have K lists.
Make min-heap.

a) Push a structure contaning sum of elements from every list (the first ones at this elements) and list of indexes `key = Sum(L[i][0]), [ix0=0, ix1=0, ix2=0]`

b) Pop the smallest element from the heap, output `key (sum)` value

c) Construct K new elements from popped one - for every increment corresponding index and update sum

```
  key - L[0][ix0] + L[0][ix0 + 1], [ix0 + 1, ix1, ix2]
  key - L[1][ix1] + L[1][ix1 + 1], [ix0, ix1 + 1, ix2]
  same for ix2
```

d) Push them into the heap

e) Repeat from b) until N smallest sums are extracted

Answer (score 0):

A Java implementation of the min heap algorithm with a simple test case:
The algorithm itself is just as described by @MBo.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class MinHeapElement {
    int sum;
    List<Integer> idx;
}
public class SumFromKLists {
    public static List<Integer> sumFromKLists(List<List<Integer>> lists, int N) {
        List<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        if(N == 0) {
            return ans;
        }
        PriorityQueue<MinHeapElement> minPq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<MinHeapElement>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MinHeapElement e1, MinHeapElement e2) {
                return e1.sum - e2.sum;
            }
        });

        MinHeapElement smallest = new MinHeapElement();
        smallest.idx = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            smallest.sum += lists.get(i).get(0);
            smallest.idx.add(0);
        }
        minPq.add(smallest);
        ans.add(smallest.sum);

        while(ans.size() < N) {
            MinHeapElement curr = minPq.poll();
            if(ans.get(ans.size() - 1) != curr.sum) {
                ans.add(curr.sum);
            }
            List<MinHeapElement> candidates = nextPossibleCandidates(lists, curr);
            if(candidates.size() == 0) {
                break;
            }
            minPq.addAll(candidates);
        }
        return ans;
    }

    private static List<MinHeapElement> nextPossibleCandidates(List<List<Integer>> lists, MinHeapElement minHeapElement) {
        List<MinHeapElement> candidates = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> currList = lists.get(i);
            int newIdx = minHeapElement.idx.get(i) + 1;
            while(newIdx < currList.size() && currList.get(newIdx) == currList.get(newIdx - 1)) {
                newIdx++;
            }
            if(newIdx < currList.size()) {
                MinHeapElement nextElement = new MinHeapElement();
                nextElement.sum = minHeapElement.sum + currList.get(newIdx) - currList.get(minHeapElement.idx.get(i));
                nextElement.idx = new ArrayList<>(minHeapElement.idx);
                nextElement.idx.set(i, newIdx);
                candidates.add(nextElement);
            }
        }
        return candidates;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add(2); list1.add(4); list1.add(7); list1.add(8);
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add(1); list2.add(3); list2.add(5); list2.add(8);

        List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
        lists.add(list1); lists.add(list2);

        sumFromKLists(lists, 11);
    }
}
```